# How does Vine implement video autoplay?

Tags: vine

The videos in Vine are autoplayed when they are visiable, how does Vine implement that, are there any methods to judge that the video are visiable?

Answer (score 4):

The embed code adds a js file. In that file they use a setInterval loop that checks if any of the vine iframe elements are in the visible viewport. If they are visible they send a 'play' message through the iframe's contentWindow. The checking code is currently:

```
var topPosition = embeds[i].getBoundingClientRect().top;
if (topPosition > -300 && topPosition < document.documentElement.clientHeight) {
```

You can take a look at their embed script which controls this (line 20-42):

https://platform.vine.co/static/scripts/embed.js